# How to decide which Convolution Neural Network architecture will work to identify the own data set?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, caffe, heatmap

I have data-set regarding chocolates. I need to detect whether it has scratches or not. I am planning to detect from Convolution Neural Network using Caffe. But how to define which neural network architecture will suit to my data-set?
Also how to generate heat values when there is any scratches in image?

I have tried detect normal image processing algorithms and it did not work.

[Abnormal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyUix.png)
[Normal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGSxn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little info you provide, the network architecture choice should be the last of your concerns. Also "trying normal image processing algorithms" is quite a vague statement.

A few points to consider

- How big is the dataset? Are the chocolate photos taken in a controlled setting where they are always similar to your example photos or are they taken in the wild, i.e. where they could have different lighting conditions, positions, etc.? Is the dataset balanced?
- How is the dataset labelled? Is it just a class for the whole image specifying normal vs abnormal? If so, you'd just be doing classification, and one way to potentially just visualise the location of the scratches (if they turn out to be the most prominent feature for the classification) is to use gradient-weighted class activation maps. On the other hand, if your dataset has labelled scratch points over images, then you can directly train your network to output heatmaps.

Once your dataset is properly set up with a training and validation set, you can just start with a baseline simple small convolutional network architecture, and then you can try out different and bigger network architectures like VGG16, ResNet, etc., and check whether they improve performance on your validation set.